# What do I do with the error in implementing the stack?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define stack 100
void push(int x);

int st[stack];
int top = -1;

int IsEmpty()
{
    if (top < 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int Isfull() 
{
    if (top >= stack - 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}

void push(int x)
{
    if (Isfull() == true)
        printf("stack is full");
    else
        st[++top]=x;
}
int pop() {
    if (IsEmpty() == true)
        printf("stack is empty.");
    else
        return stack[top--];/// There is an error in this part. (expression must have pointer-to-object type)
}

int main()
{
    push(3);


}




int pop() {
        if (IsEmpty() == true)
            printf("stack is empty.");
        else
            return stack[top--];There is an error in this part. (expression must have pointer-to-object type)
```

expression must have pointer-to-object type
    Stack is being implemented as an array And then there's this error.
 What should I do?
    Is this a Syntex error? Tell me the wrong part.
    and If there is anything else that needs to be corrected, please let me know.

C language is difficult. Have you all experienced this kind of error?

Comment: Did you mean `st[top--]`?  `stack` is an integer.

Comment: SideNote: Actually, `stack` is not even an integer, it is a macro that resolves to `100`. Therefore, the code is equivalent to `100[top--]` or `(top--)[100]`, but neither of those work because `top` is also an integer and not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`return stack[top--];` same as `return 100[top--];`.

I suspect you wanted `return st[top--];`

Use a different name for the stack size too to avoid such name collisions.

```
// #define stack 100
#define STACK_SIZE 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 problems:

1. A simple typo:

   ```
   return stack[top--]; ==> return st[top--];
   ```

`stack` is the array size but your array is named `st`

2. Missing return value

This code has no return value when the stack is empty.

```
int pop() {
    if (IsEmpty() == true)
        printf("stack is empty.");
        // No return value here
    else
```

Even if the stack is empty you must return a value. So you need to handle that in another way. One option is to return a dummy value (e.g. zero), another is to exit the program or change the pop-function signature so that it can tell whether it was succesful. For instance:

```
// Option 1: Return dummy value
int pop() {
    if (IsEmpty()) return 0;
    return stack[top--];
} 

// Option 2: Exit program
int pop() {
    if (IsEmpty()) exit(1);
    return stack[top--];
} 


// Option 3: Let the function tell whether is was a success
int pop(int* data) {
    if (IsEmpty()) return 0;
    *data = stack[top--];
    return 1;
}
```

The last pop-function returns 1 on success - zero otherwise.

3. Wrong logic

This function:

```
int IsEmpty()
{
    if (top < 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

is wrong. Change it to:

```
int IsEmpty()
{
    if (top < 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

or more simple

```
int IsEmpty()
{
    return (top < 0);
}
```